# I want to control two array with one ngFor loop in <tr > element

Tags: angular

```
                                      <tr *ngFor="let element of serialNo,listArray">
                                        <td class="text-center"> {{element}}</td> 
                                        <td class="text-center"> {{element.title}}</td>                                             
                                      </tr>
```

`serialNo` and `listArray` are arrays I want to display data of respective arrays  in rows

Answer (score 0):

```
*ngFor="let element of serialNo.concat(listArray)"
```

Will do if you just want to display data.

Comment: then how do we pick index of listarray to display data

Comment: You don't. You asked to iterate over two arrays, that is how.